# Storing Photos from iOS Application into server

Tags: mysql, ios, sql, objective-c, uiimage

My question is about performance. I've  built an iOS application that takes photos and stores them into a database.

Is it more efficient to store the base64_encoded image string into a database field or store  the file in a folder and only store the file path in the database, then encode the image back into a base64_encoded image when it is retrieved by the application?

My current approach is storing the image in a folder and converting it into a base64_encoded image string when the app fetches the images from the server. I return them in groups of 15 images at a time and this works fine but there is a delay when the server is converting the 15 images into base64 string format.

Thanks for any opinions, suggestions or advice.

Comment: So you're talking about storing images on a phone and uploading, or on a server and downloading?

Comment: Hey, yes, i'm talking about taking images using the phone and uploading them to a server. They are downloaded from the server at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

This is application specific - What is your end goal? Storing base64 strings will be of a larger performance hit, simply because base64 strings can get quite large in size. A path string would generally be smaller. But - if you don't store that image data, you don't own the data and if the path changes, your implementation will break.

Comment: Oh okay. So the way it works right now is each user has a designated  folder that is created when they sign up to use the app. I convert the base64 image string back into an image, assign it a unique file name a combination of the member's ID and datetime the image was uploaded and then store the path to that file in the database. When I want to retrieve it, I get the image from the file path, encode it back into base64 and send it to the app which then displays it on the image. So I always have access to the data, just thought storing the base64 image string would reduce processing time.